# Text input to have whatever left as width

Tags: css, angular

I want to have a Tags input (just like the stackoverflow's one) where users can type their chosen tags and it shows inside the input.
I decided to do it inside of a ul where the input is the last li:

```
  <ul class="tag-box">
    <li class="tags" *ngFor="let tag of tags">{{tag.name}}<a class="close"></a></li>
    <li class="new-tag"><input class="input-tag" type="text"></li>
  </ul>
```

But the problem is the width of the input is always small by default while I want it to take all the remaining width:

my css:

```
.tag-box {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: arial;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #F39F19;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
.tag-box li {
  padding: 4px 6px;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
.tag-box li.tags {
  background: #F1C617;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  margin: 4px 3px;
  position: relative;
}
.tag-box li .input-tag {
  color: #000;
  height: 24px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: none;
}
```

Is there a way where my input my input can take whatever left of space as width according to the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way you could do it, I'm adding 3 things. You'll eventually want to give it a `min-width` and make it wrap though.

```css
.tag-box {
  display: flex;
}
.tag-box .new-tag {
  flex: 1
}
.tag-box li .input-tag {
  width: 100%;
}
```